# flash as3 and external text config file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My goal was to have an external text file config for a client.  I didnt want to go through a crazy xml thing, I just wanted it to be simple to change.
I started with a urlLoader, and was able to dynamically generate an object no problem. This is the function which parses and sets the properties of the object.

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void//initializes the config
{
var myString = String(e.target.data);
//trace(e.target.data);
//trace(myString);
var propsArray:Array = myString.split("\n"); 


for (var i = 0; i < propsArray.length; i++){
    var thisLine:Array = propsArray[i].split("=");
    var thisPropName:String = thisLine[0];
        thisPropName = thisPropName.replace(rex,'');
    var thisPropValue:String = thisLine[1];
    thisPropValue = thisPropValue.replace(rex,'');
trace("thePropName is: " + thisPropName);
    trace("thePropValue is: " + thisPropValue);
config[thisPropName] = thisPropValue;
}
```

}

The text file would just look something like:

> gateway = "http://thePathto/theFile.php
>    toast = sonofabitch
>    timer = 5000
>    xSpeed = 5.0

That way, I could just put a little bit of as3 code in, type what things I wanted configured, then all I would have to do was type config.timer and

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(Number(config.timer));
```

I think the problem is load order and scope.  The config.timer is not created yet, so the timer is unable to access the value of the config.timer.

Comment: Allow me to suggest that `XML` will be insanely easier than plain text to deal with and manage - it will also only take you max a couple hours of tutorials to fully understand.

Comment: I know discussion of the config format this isn't really part of the question, but there are great formats out there already for this explicit purpose, with excellent AS3 loading tools. XML is a good example, as is JSON. XML is built into the language, and JSON is a fantastic lightweight alternative. You can load JSON with the excellent 'as3corelib': https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

Comment: Oh, here's a good example of using as3corelib for loading and decoding JSON: http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.co.nz/2011/02/working-with-json-and-as3-part-2.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at using XML in future projects of this nature, however to answer your question:

> I think the problem is load order and scope. The `config.timer` is not created yet, so the timer is unable to access the value of the `config.timer`.

Correct, you will need to initialize your `Timer` within the `onLoaded()` method, as the data will be received asynchronously and is not available until this happens.

Answer (score -1):

ok not long ago i had created a download manager that uses this exact concept.
The link below will take you straight to the website where you can download the full swf including my source files. also this website is a good place for resources

http://ffiles.com/flash/web_applications_and_data/dynamic_download_manager_3529.html

Below is my loader:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("settings.txt"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoad);

function onDataLoad(evt:Event)
{

box1.text = evt.target.data.Id_1;
box2.text = evt.target.data.Id_2;
box3.text = evt.target.data.Id_3;
box4.text = evt.target.data.Id_4;
box5.text = evt.target.data.Id_5;
}
```

Add some dynamic text boxes to stage and name them "box1, box2 ect..." 
Now creat your text file:

```
Id_1=this is what ever you want
&Id_2=this is what ever you want
&Id_3=this is what ever you want
&Id_4=this is what ever you want
&Id_5=this is what ever you want
```

Hope this helps.